# Kotlin DSL scope control on external non-changeable classes (similar to @DslMarker)

Tags: kotlin

I have lots of external classes (generated externally; not under my control), which do not come with a builder and which are rather cumbersome to create. However using `apply` it is rather easy to build them, e.g.:

```
SomeOfTheObjects().apply {
  someProperty = SomeOtherComplexObject().apply {
    someOtherProperty = "..."
  }
}
```

Now I like the way it works with the receiver, but I would like to prevent that I can set `someProperty` within `SomeOtherComplexObject`. If the classes were under my control, it would suffice to put a `@DslMarker` on that class, but as they aren't, the only other way that came to my mind, was to use `also` instead without renaming the parameter, e.g.:

```
SomeOfTheObjects().also {
  it.someProperty = SomeOtherComplexObject().also {
    it.someOtherProperty = "..."
    //it.someProperty will not work if SomeOtherComplexObject has no such property
  }
}
```

While it works, it now has tons of `it.` in the code and I was wondering, whether it is possible to have some similar behaviour as with the `@DslMarker` in place.

What I tried is a mixture of the following:

```
@DslMarker
annotation class DemoMarker

@DemoMarker
inline fun <T> T.build(@DemoMarker builder : T.() -> Unit) = this.apply(builder)
```

"mixture", because I ended up putting the annotation everywhere, but this doesn't have any effect. If I put it on a class it works as expected. Did I miss something and it is actually possible somehow? Or does anyone have an appropriate workaround for this, besides using `also`?

Comment: Can you inherit from that third-party classes? Probably inherit and mark your classes with `@DslMaker`?

Comment: That would be possible, but there are about ~4k classes in there... they are obviously generated from a schema. Maybe I can get the schema from somewhere and then just generate the sources from scratch and add the annotation while generating :-) still I think the question stays valid... and I hope there is some other workaround for this :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For third party classes you can use the DslMarker annotation on receiver types as explained [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/scope-control-for-builder-like-dsls/2289/2).

```
@DslMarker
@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS, AnnotationTarget.TYPE)
annotation class TestDsl

fun build1(builder: (@TestDsl DslReceiver1).() -> Unit) {}
```

Comment: perfect! Now I just need to setup such an extension function (like `apply`/`also`) first, but that's easier than anything else :-)